# Build array based on the function of another array

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following a lot in my code. Can I do it as a one liner?

```
function anotherFunction(array)
{
    new_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
        new_array.push(someFunction(array[i]));
    }  
    return new_array;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, remove the newline's ;) *just kidding*.

Comment: array.push should be new_array.push and return array should be return new_array, I think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is to "[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)" the array over a function:

```
var arr  = [...];
var arr2 = arr.map(someFunction);
```

Comment: A note that `Array.prototype.map` is ES5 and not Compatible with older browsers would be nice though =)

Comment: I think this may not be supported in IE8. I think it could be pretty easily tacked onto the array prototype; I just need to recall if doing that would have some sort of caveat.

Comment: The link to the documentation provides a backwards compatibility shim and the much used ES5Shim compatibility library includes it IIRC.

Comment: It is not supported in IE8 http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 and ben Since it can be implemented trivially in user code, that is pretty irrelevant. A more correct thing to say is that it doesn't work **out of the box** in IE8. Stuff like File IO is **truly** unsupported in IE8 and should be differentiated.

Comment: @Esailija That's totally correct, i just like it when i see a decent note if methods require a shim in older browsers, as it provides useful information on the first glance forfuture visiting users who might not read the mdn article.

Comment: Nice answer anyway =)

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArray = array.map(someFunction);
```

You should note that this may fail on IE8 if you need to support that though

http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map

Answer (score 0):

if you also want it fast... Array.prototype.map is not so fast as a loop.

http://jsperf.com/array-map-vs-loop/2

so:

```
function customMap(a,c){
 var b=[],l=a.length;
 while(l--){
  b[l]=c(a[l]);
 }
 return b;
}
```

and return it with

```
var newArray=customMap(oldArray,function);
```

this is very fast.

you can also create a custom prototype.

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'CMap',{value:function(c){
 var b=[],l=this.length;while(l--){b[l]=c(this[l])}
 return b;
},writable:false,enumerable:false});
```

and use it like map.

```
var newArray=oldArray.CMap(function);
```

**EDIT**

here is the test on jsperf...

http://jsperf.com/custom-vs-map

every variable is defined outside the test... so speed is based only on the custom function.

and this works on all browsers.

Comment: Variable name length doesn't affect performance so you didn't relaly have to minify it :P But yes, Array.prototype.map involves far more convoluted semantics than a common sense loop so it's slower.

Comment: nah... i really tested ... i just got the first link of jsperf... push vs direct setting && map vs custom function are slower... also the while-- loop is faster in real world. you can't even test the while -- loop in jsperf.

Comment: almost there, don't put code in setup and do work in the function http://jsperf.com/custom-vs-map/2

Comment: yea jsperf is actually really hard (or well, unintuitive) to use if you want correct results

Comment: yeah some ppl define everything in the test snippets... u have to put everything that has nothing to do with your test case outside...as i just learned from you in the preparation code html in <script>

Comment: so this is 6-7 times faster than the normal map.. and it's compatible with prolly all browsers with javascript support.